# Many errors appeared after i added a recycler-view dependency in my project

Tags: android, aapt2

My app worked fine and compilated untill i added

`com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1` in my project.

Here are my errors:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
C:\Users\Smith\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-25.3.1.aar\455a076f8084ee34b277fdfdb97836e0\res\values\values.xml
Error:(203, 5) error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.
Error:(203, 5) error: resource android:attr/font not found.
Error:(203, 5) error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.
Error:(203, 5) error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
Error:(203, 5) error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
C:\Users\Smith\AndroidStudioProjects\DontSleepManager\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Error:(314) resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.
Error:(314) resource android:attr/font not found.
Error:(314) resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.
Error:(314) resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
Error:(314) resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
Error:failed linking references.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
Information:BUILD FAILED in 29s
Information:15 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

[image]

If i add the line

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

in gradle-properties then i get next warnings:

[image]

Please help me to figure out that

Comment: did you try cleaning your project; if yes then try: go to files -->invalidate cache/restart'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1` to `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1`.

And take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification) question